# Changing certain characters in a list at a specific position

Tags: python, string, list

My goal is to take in a list and then output it backwards.
Right now my input/output is:

```
['1', '[2,[4,5]]', '3'] 

['3', '[]5,4[,2]', '1']
```

As you can see from the output the brackets are facing the wrong way. I am trying to use the replace function, but it replaces every position with the bracket.

The correct output should look like this.

```
['3', '[[5,4],2]', '1']
```

Here is my code.

```
organizeList = ['1','[2,[4,5]]','3']
print("Format should be similar to '1, 2, [3, 4], 5'")
#organizeList.append(input("Enter a list: ")
tempList = []
otherList = []
testString = ""
lastString = ""
print(organizeList)
for p in range(len(organizeList)-1, -1, -1):
    if (organizeList[p].startswith('[') == True):
        for showList in organizeList[p]:
            testString = testString + showList
        for x in range(len(testString)-1, -1, -1):
            if (testString[x] == ']'):
                testString = testString.replace(testString[x], '[')
            elif (testString[x] == '['):
                testString = testString.replace(testString[x], ']')
            lastString = lastString + testString[x]
        tempList.append(lastString)
    else:
        tempList.append(organizeList[p])
print(tempList)
```

I'm still learning python, so if you have any tips and tricks on how to clean up my code as well, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's wrong with your code, but you should just remap all left-bracket to right-bracket and vice versa, like this:

```
>>> remap = {ord('['): ']', ord(']'): '['}
>>> L = ['1', '[2,[4,5]]', '3']
>>> [s[::-1].translate(remap) for s in reversed(L)]
['3', '[[5,4],2]', '1']
```

Comment: How do I add the part [s[::-1].translate(remap) for s in reversed(L)] into my code? I keep getting an error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a rather simple fix. Not sure if my whole method is correct, but this works.

```
organizeList = ['1','[2,[4,5]]','3']
print("Format should be similar to '1, 2, [3, 4], 5'")
#organizeList.append(input("Enter a list: ")
tempList = []
otherList = []
testString = ""
lastString = ""
remap = {ord('['): ']', ord(']'): '['}
print(organizeList)
for p in range(len(organizeList)-1, -1, -1):
    if (organizeList[p].startswith('[') == True):
        for showList in organizeList[p]:
            testString = testString + showList
        for x in range(len(testString)-1, -1, -1):
            if (testString[x] == ']'):
                lastString = lastString + '['
            elif (testString[x] == '['):
                lastString = lastString + ']'
            else:
                lastString = lastString + testString[x]
        tempList.append(lastString)
    else:
        tempList.append(organizeList[p])
print(tempList)
```

Like I said I'm still learning python, so if anyone has any tips for me please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way

```
my_list_of_string = ['1', '[2,[4,5]]', '3']

print("Input : ",my_list_of_string)
# This function basically replace '[' to ']' and ']' to '['
# That's why when we will reverse the string it will maintain the
# parenthesis
def reverse_list_string(ls):
    c = []
    for ch in ls:
        if ch == "[":
            c.append("]")
        elif ch == "]":
            c.append("[")
        else:
            c.append(ch)
    c.reverse()
    new_reverse_string = "".join(c)
    return new_reverse_string

reverse_ls=[]
for ls in my_list_of_string:
    new_string = reverse_list_string(ls)
    reverse_ls.append(new_string)

reverse_ls.reverse()
print("Output : ", reverse_ls)
```

**Sample Input/Output**

```
Input :  ['1', '[2,[4,5]]', '3']
Output :  ['3', '[[5,4],2]', '1']
```